# how to add global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to add global.asax to my project. When I'm using this way:

1. Open Solution Explorer.
2. Right-click on the project.
3. Add New Item.
4. VB or C#
5. Web.
6. General.
7. Global Application Class.

there is no such options like Global Application Class

When I'm trying this way:

1. Create an empty new project.
2. Go to that folder and copy the Global.asax file.
3. Go to your project and in solution explorer paste it on root.
4. Open Global.asax file and change namespace match to your namespace.
5. In solution explorer right click on Global.asax and pick View Markup and change inherits match to your namespace.

there is no View Markup option.
any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are clicking the PROJECT and not the SOLUTION? That's the only way i can see that behavior. Also try to use the "search" function, write 'Global'

Answer (score 0):

1-)create empty new project
2-)copy the Global.asax file in new project
3-)go to your project and in solution explorer past it on roo
4-)open Global.asax and change namespace to your project namespace